# Creating list from predicate

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate as:

```
delta(q1,a,q2).
delta(q1,b,q3).
delta(q2,a,q4).
delta(q2,a,q3).
delta(q3,a,q1).
```

and I want to convert them to list like this:
`nfatodfa([(q1,a,q2),(q1,b,q3),(q2,a,q4),(q2,a,q3),(q3,a,q1)],L)`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might want to use is **findall/3** to construct this list:

```
?- findall(d(X,Y,Z), delta(X,Y,Z), L).

L = [d(q1,a,q2),d(q1,b,q3),d(q2,a,q4),d(q2,a,q3),d(q3,a,q1)]
```

Note that this makes a list of compound terms using functor `d` to hold things, which is a little different than what you outlined.  However the parentheses alone, eg. `(q1,a,q2)`, can be a little tricky to work with.  If you just want the bare triplets, do this:

```
?- findall((X,Y,Z), delta(X,Y,Z), L).

L = [(q1,a,q2), (q1,b,q3), (q2,a,q4), (q2,a,q3), (q3,a,q1)]
```